# Postcards, stamps and mailbox at Manila airport?

Tags: mail, manila, mnl

I'm having a stupidly hard time finding postcards and stamps in Manila -- it looks like postal mail has been comprehensively obsoleted here by SMS!

**Can I find postcards, stamps and a mailbox to send them off at Manila Ninoy Aquino Airport?**  Terminals 1 or 3, to be specific, either landside or airside.

Comment: If you can't find it, let me know. I have a friend who works at the airport and can help you.

Comment: Thanks for the offer, but finally found postcards at the Shangri-La's gift shop and optimistically hoping that the concierge at my hotel follows through on buying stamps and sending them.  Still happy to accept an answer for this question though!

Comment: Good then, I will ask her sometime how does she get the stamps. I know she does because she use them to send work related mail.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

http://125.60.203.88/miaa/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=110:mail-service&catid=75:airport-facilities&Itemid=72

Post Office

> The NAIA Terminal 2 Post Office is located at the South Wing of the
>   Arrival Lobby beside the Pass Control Office

Post Box

> Located within the area of the Post Office, accessible even on
>   weekends.
>
> Pick-up Schedule Monday to Friday: 10:30AM

Stamps

> Postage stamps are sold by retail shops near Gate 1 of the South Wing
>   Pre-departure Hall and infront of the Philippine Airlines Business
>   Class Counter, Check-in Hall of the North Wing.  These shops are
>   authorized by the Philippine Postal Corp.  These shops are authorized
>   by the Philippine Postal Corp.
>
> Business Hours Daily: 5:00AM to 9:00PM

Comment: Thanks, but that's Terminal 2, used only by Philippine Airlines :(

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Philippine Postal Corporation website](https://www.phlpost.gov.ph/post-office-location.php), no postal offices are available at Manila Airport. Likewise checking the [airport map](http://125.60.203.88/miaa/index.php?option=com_content&view=category&layout=blog&id=9&Itemid=93) for all four terminals failed to find anything related to postal services.

However there are plenty of postal offices in downtown Manila, so perhaps you could try your luck there next time.

Comment: What about a letter box? Or a store selling postcards and stamps? Those are quite common on other airports I've seen.

Comment: @drat I've checked the airport map and at least online there's no information. Perhaps someone could visit the airport and find something.

Comment: yeah, and I would be more surprised if they actually put the letter boxes on the map.

Answer (score 1):

There is a postal office just on the right side of domestic departures.
And we bought the stamps in a little shop just at international departures.

Comment: There are three separate international terminals, which one did you use and what was the shop called?